# ActionbarSherlock - how do I handle it when someone clicks a dropdown nav item?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am working from the ActionbarSherlock example for the Dropdown navigation. And I have something like this:

```
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

And that works to show the dropdown list in the nav area. But when I select an item from the dropdown, it does nothing. How do I determine what item was selected and go to that activity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

With the line above, you're supplying `this` as the `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` that will receive the callbacks for when a navigation item is selected.

Since it sounds like you don't have any compile errors, your activity should have a method somewhere with the following footprint:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) { ... }
```

That's where you'll want to implement your logic for changing activities, fragments etc based on the selected navigation item.

Comment: thank you! And that method should exist in every activity, right? So I would replicate the code in every activity? Is that how it is meant to work?

Comment: Personally, I don't fancy replicating code, so I'd probably factor it out into an (abstract) base activity, from which other activities can then extend.  Alternatively, you could have a top-level activity and swap out fragments based on the selected navigation item. Whichever you choose, I'd avoid doubling up code in different places for the sake of maintainability.